# List only contacts marked as visible on your phone

Tags: android

I researched a lot and apparently it is an easy solution to solve this problem. I want to list only the contacts that are marked in the phone configuration to be displayed.

I have this implementation, but it lists all the contacts.

```
public void showVisibleContacts(){
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP
    };
    /* checked is visible or 0 not visible */
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int columnName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        Log.e("Contact: ", "columnName: " + columnName);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever solved this problem? could help ?

**Edit**: add more infos

Example:
Configurations in Smartphone

Access configs in options from [Contacts]

Step 1
http://bytefreaks.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/02-Select-Contacts-to-display-576x1024.png

Step 2
http://bytefreaks.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/03-Make-sure-All-Contacts-is-selected-576x1024.png

Comment: What is "the phone configuration to be displayed"?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but there a few ways contacts can be filtered/hidden.

The most obvious is the soft [deleted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#DELETED) flag which can be used exactly as you have tried to use the in-visible-group flag (which says 'at least one of my raw contacts is visible'). You could just as easily mean contacts you have favourited though - in that case you need the [starred](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#STARRED) flag